# Clap switch working on 220 Volts AC

Tags: switches, flipflop, sound

I have made this clap switch.It is working fine presently. I need suggestions for improvement for its long term use.[image: Clap Switch]
Specifically I want to know if the capacitor based power supply is okay in this circuit and wont damage the components in long run?

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: What about safety? I don't see a transformer for isolation. Why not use it?

Comment: This circuit can not be isolated because it uses a Triac which has to be connected to the 220 Volt AC. However caution is needed. 1. Dont touch the circuit while connected to line. 2. Enclose the circuit in a plastic box to avoid shock.

Comment: I'd say that the supply is fine here since the circuit doesn't need to be ever touched by the operator and galvanic isolation is not needed. Adding a transformer would increase the cost. If you worry about the components (why?) then you'd want to isolate the drive and sensing from the triac.